# Continue execution after sending file to client

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating dynamically a pdf file and sending it to the client:

```
private function createPdf($foo)
{
    //Delete pdf file if it exists
    if(file_exists('path_to_directory' . $foo->getId() . '.pdf'))
        unlink('path_to_directory' . $foo->getId() . '.pdf');

    //Create new pdf file
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
        $this->renderView(
            'AcmeFooBundle:Default:pdfTemplate.html.twig', array(
                'foo' => $foo)
        ),
        'path_to_directory' . $foo->getId() . '.pdf'
    );

    // open the file in a binary mode
    $fp = fopen('path_to_directory' . $foo->getId() . '.pdf', 'rb');
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.pdf"');

    // dump the picture and stop the script
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
}
```

This function works right, but I'd want to continue execution after sending the file to the client to render a "success" template and send it to the client. I've tried things like removing `exit;` and this: [Continue execution after calling php passthru() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798070/continue-execution-after-calling-php-passthru-function), but no success. Any idea?

Comment: explain '*but no success*'.

Comment: @nl-x - I don't understand how to apply the link example to this case. All I've tried thrown an error.

Comment: be more precise. What error ? By the way, `passthru` and `fpassthru` are completely different things.

Comment: @nl-x - *File not found: (current route)*. (not file path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved it adding a Javascript event to the file generation button:

**Pure JS:**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        function redirectToMeeting() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href="url_to_go";
            }, 2000);

        }
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('create-file-button')) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('create-file-button')[0].addEventListener('click', redirectToMeeting);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Then, when the button is clicked, the new file is created and sent to the client, and then (after 2 seconds) the client is redirected to the `url_to_go`.

**JQuery:**

```
    $(function(){
        $('#create-file-button').submit(function(ev) {
            $("#continue").show();
        });
    });
```

When the form is submitted, a new button (`#continue`) will be shown which lets the user go to the next page (`url_to_go`).